# OSMDroid Throwing OutOfMemoryError when parsing geoJSON on resume

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm populating an osm map with markers using parseGeoJSON, it works fine when the activity is first started, but if the activity is resumed I get `Throwing OutOfMemoryError`

Here's my code, it's run from an AsyncTask.

```
KmlDocument lines = new KmlDocument();
    Drawable defaultMarker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin);
    Bitmap defaultBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)defaultMarker).getBitmap();
    Style defaultStyle = new Style(defaultBitmap, 0x901010AA, 8.0f, 0x20AA1010);

    try {
        lines.parseGeoJSON(IOUtils.toString(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.line), "UTF-8"));
        linesOver = (FolderOverlay) lines.mKmlRoot.buildOverlay(map, defaultStyle, null, lines);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
```

Comment: doesn't osmbonous pack have a read from stream method? Try using that instead of stream to string to bonuspack.

Comment: @spy not that I can see, it seems to only read strings or files

Comment: i'd suggest you open a ticket and a PR. looks very simple to add. A streamed approach "may" resolve your issue. You could also try a delayed resume. Also check if largeHeap is set in the manifest

Comment: https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/KML#limits